# Stomp ruby gem does not publish on dead letter exchange queue Rabbitmq

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rabbitmq, stomp, dead-letter

I'm trying to publish on a queue (RabbitMQ) with *x-dead-letter-exchange* and *x-message-ttl header* via ruby stomp gem https://github.com/stompgem/stomp

It works fine via management panel, but I can't see my message published using this code:

```
    require 'stomp'

    client = Stomp::Client.new("guest", "guest", "localhost", 61613)
    client.publish("/queue/queue_with_dlx_header", "hello world!")
```

If I try this on a "normal" queue, the message gets published as expected.

Any advice?

Comment: I'm using RabbitMQ 3.0.0 on Ubuntu Oneiric

Comment: how long is your TTL? you might find it useful to make this something more like a few minutes so you can see if it is coming into the queue before being expired

Comment: 1 min ttl but nothing shows up

Comment: I tried on a queue with ttl header and the same happens. I tried it on a queue with just the x-dead-letter-exchange header and the message gets published.

Comment: I ended up using carrot gem to publish on the queue.